# String Concatenation vs Comma in a functions return statement

Tags: python

I want to write a function that will return a string that includes a given argument with the type int or float.
so for example :

```
def exampleFunc(variable):
    return 'Your Variable is ' + str(variable)
print(exampleFunc(3))
```

when run it outputs :

```
>>> Your Variable is 3
```

But when using a comma in the return statement as follows :

```
def exampleFunc(variable):
    return 'Your Variable is', variable
print(exampleFunc(3))
```

It outputs :

```
>>> ('Your Variable is', 3)
```

Can you please explain the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: you are returning 2 values as a tuple so it prints the tuple. It is similar to you just saying `print(('Your Variable is', 3))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns a `tuple` of (`str`, `int`):

```
def exampleFunc(variable):
    return 'Your Variable is', variable
```

It's **exactly** the same as:

```
def exampleFunc(variable):
    return ('Your Variable is', variable)
```

This for the other hand concatenates the `variable` to a string, and returns that:

```
def exampleFunc(variable):
    return 'Your Variable is ' + str(variable)
```

This is a correct way to do this, alternatively you could insert the `variable` into the string with [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) and return that: `return f'Your Variable is {variable}'`.

Comment: Can this tuple be typecasted to a string? or do i have to use string concatenation ?

Comment: @Elbasel There's no such thing as typecasting tuple to string. You should simply use concatenation like you've done, or alternatively you f-strings: `return f'Your Variable is {variable}'`

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you are merging the string with the variable due to the +.

In the second case you are returning these two seperate by putting the comma inbetween and since you can always return only one thing, python automatically puts both inside a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you understand what's going on behind the scenes:

```
def exampleFunc(variable):
    x = 'Your Variable is ' + str(variable)
    y = 'Your Variable is', variable
    print(type(x))
    print(type(y))

exampleFunc(3)
```

The printout of the code above is:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'tuple'>
```

Hence it is clear that the first case returns an element of type `str`, and the second case returns an element of type `tuple`.

If we "dig" into that tuple, then we shall find out that it consists of two elements - one of type `str` and the other of the type of `variable`.